# Java Map for unique object instances?

Tags: java, reference, hashmap, instance

A library I use contains a certain object type, `LackingObject` (some type), which lacks an attribute of type `Ext` (some type). If I was able to change the `LackingObject` class, I would simply add an attribute with type `Ext`, but `LackingObject` cannot be changed, nor extended. What I'd do now in languages like `C` or `C++` is to create a `Map` that maps `LackingObjects` to `Exts`, which, in Java, would (somewhat equivalently) look like

```
Map<LackingObject, Ext> object_extension = new HashMap<>();
```

so whenever I encounter a `LackingObject` in my code for the first time, I can call

```
LackingObject o = ...;
Ext value = compute_value_for(o, ...);
object_extension.put(o, value);
```

and then, to recall that added attribute, I would call

```
Ext resolved = object_extension.get(o);
```

This however will not work, as the default `HashMap` behavior is to map the results of `Object::hashCode`, not `Objects`, to values, so if I had two (apart from the `Ext` value) `equal` `LackingObjects`, they could not both be a unique key in a `java.util.HashMap`.

The question: In Java, is there at least one of the following:

- a way to let the standard libraries map object instances to values?
- a way to receive an unique identifier for an object instance?

I found a 7 year old post somewhat related to this topic, but I hope things have changed during the years.

The final resort would be to create a wrapper class,

```
class Wrapper{
    LackingObject o;
    Ext v;
}
```

but that overall seems to me like an inferior solution, as we would be adding a potentially redundant new object type to the project structure, instead of just adding a few statements.

(Unrelated to the topic, as this part of the problem is specific to my current condition, but this 'inferior solution' would also require me to change a lot of already existing source code, which I would happily avoid, if possible.)

Comment: What is the library?

Comment: Why don't you just encapsulate the LackingObject in a class that includes the attribute?  It's not an inferior approach.  Quite standard and extensible, and much more readable than what you're describing.  Read Effective Java, favor composition over inheritence...

Comment: @Oliver ANTLR, the `LackingObject` is a `ParseTree`. I need to add a custom `IScope` to each `ParseTree` node to properly resolve symbols from within scopes.

Comment: @AmirAfghani Feels like if I wrapped the `LackingObject` in a custom `Wrapper`, other programmers that used my interface or reused my code or something and would not need the `Ext` attribute, would have to unwrap the `Wrapper` and cut out the `LackingObject`, because it might not be lacking for them. Honestly doesn't feel good tbh.

Comment: Why don't just override `equals()` in the `LackingObject` class? This way you decide when two objects are the same, regarding their variable values, for example. Equals won't check for hashcodes if you override it

Comment: @aran The asker cannot change the class ("but LackingObject cannot be changed, nor extended").

Comment: @aran The problem is that two separate `LackingObject` instances can be exactly the same, except for the `Ext` value. No matter how one implements `equals()`, in this case, it would just return `true` for those particular instances.

Comment: @iota good note, didn't read that...

Comment: @CaptainTrojan I gotcha. But how about including the unknown Ext value to the comparation? Like creating blank instances of Ext (until they are set) and adding their hashcodes to it, for example. Anyway, as your requirements state, I believe the best option would be iota's answer

Comment: I suggest you add a section at the bottom of the question describing your actual situation with ANTLR. Keep your simplified description as-is at the top, as it makes a good introduction, and not that many people are familiar with ANTLR.

Comment: @BasilBourque But the question is not about ANTLR. It is *clearly* about `LackingObjects` and `Exts`.

Comment: @aran That would work for putting values into the map, but not for retrieving. You couldn't implement `TheMap.get(LackingObject) => Ext`, because the `Ext` value is not included in the `LackingObject` itself.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan totally right, indeed. Reading it twice doesn't even make sense, as you wouldn't have to store the Ext in any Map if LackingObject could hold an Ext instance. This question was a good one, taking into account your needs and limits. +1

Comment: @aran I feel like I should add that I was actually wrong when I claimed that even if you *could* override `equals()` in `LackingObject`, there was no way to do it. There actually is: `LackingObject.equals(LackingObject other) { return this == other }`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`IdentityHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) for this purpose. According to its documentation:

> This class implements the Map interface with a hash table, using reference-equality in place of object-equality when comparing keys (and values). In other words, in an IdentityHashMap, two keys k1 and k2 are considered equal if and only if (k1==k2). (In normal Map implementations (like HashMap) two keys k1 and k2 are considered equal if and only if (k1==null ? k2==null : k1.equals(k2)).)
> This class is not a general-purpose Map implementation! While this class implements the Map interface, it intentionally violates Map's general contract, which mandates the use of the equals method when comparing objects. This class is designed for use only in the rare cases wherein reference-equality semantics are required.

Answer (score 2):

## `System.identityHashCode`

Digging in [the guts](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/IdentityHashMap.java) of [`IdentityHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) (obtained thanks to [Answer by Unmitigated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65532692/642706)), I found an answer to the partial question:

> What is the way to receive a unique identifier for an object instance?

…with the key being: [`System.identityHashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object))

with the signature of

```
int identityHashCode(Object);
```

To quote the Javadoc:

> Returns the same hash code for the given object as would be returned by the default method hashCode(), whether or not the given object's class overrides hashCode(). The hash code for the null reference is zero.